# Return a promise in a factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a factory where I wanna return a promise inside a function but my controller says everytime something like:

```
Provider 'personFactory' must return a value from $get factory method.
```

My factory:

```
(function () {
        'use strict';
        angular
            .module('testApp')
            .factory('personFactory', personFactory);

        personFactory.$inject = ['storage'];


        function personFactory(storage) {

            storage.getData().then(function (response) {

                return {
                    allData: function () {
                        return response
                    }
                }

            });
        }

    })();
```

My controller:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('testApp')
        .controller('menuListController', menuListController);

    menuListController.$inject = ['$scope', 'personFactory', '$rootScope'];

    function menuListController($scope, personFactory) {

        $scope.fromFactory = personFactory.allData();

        console.log($scope.fromFactory)
    }
})();
```

I think I have to double return both the functions, but can't get the syntax right to call it also in the controller if that is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your factory definition has to return something, that's the problem:

```
    function personFactory(storage) {

        return storage.getData().then(function (response) {

            return {
                allData: function () {
                    return response
                }
            }

        });
    }
```

Now, I don't know if that's what you really need.  I usually return a function or object in the factory that then I use.

With your approach you will invoke getData only once and receive the promise directly in your controller.

I like it, now that I think about it :)

But! Looking at the rest of your code, I think you're not expecting to get the promise after all.
You would have to do something like this anyway:

```
personFactory.then(function () {
    $scope.fromFactory = data.allData();
});
```

Which again makes me think you don't need to do that allData business.  Here's what I'd do:

```
function personFactory(storage) {
    return storage.getData();
}

personFactory.then(function (response) {
    $scope.fromFactory = response;
});
```

How does that look?

Comment: Does this mean I have to return 2 functions inside my controller ? something like .getdata().allData()

Comment: @Dennis: No, `storage.getData()` is called in the factory, the controller sees only the object with the `allData` method (or the promise for it)

Comment: How can I bring it back to my controller, it keeps saying that they are both no functions, whatever I do. Thats was the problem I was running into before. because     $scope.fromFactory = personFactory.getData(); or     $scope.fromFactory = personFactory.allData(); both return the error that they are not functions :(

Comment: @Dennis, I've edited my answer, I think it will help you.

Comment: Oh men you are my true hero, was really twisting my head around this problem. I had to add a reponse also in the controller like this:            personFactory.then(function (response) {
                $scope.fromFactory = response.allData();
            });

Comment: But, I don't know why I approach this with a technique like this. In my head I thought maby if I generate the data from another factory the 'storage' and than pass it into another factory and make like 10 different functions (form the storage data) where I can call the one that contains the data I want in the controller. Maby I could do it in one factory but this just looks 'better' for me. I don't have to do it really for the speed cause this is just a small personal application but really many many many thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome!  Promises took me a bit to wrap my head around them, but it's worth it.